# Verificar se String possui caracter '+'

Tags: java, string, replace

Preciso procurar em uma string se ela possui o caracter + , dessa forma:

```
teste = teste.replaceAll("+", "e");
```

porém me retorna esse erro:

> java.util.regex.PatternsSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+'

Comment: Tenta escapar o caractere colocando uma barra invertida na frente: `\+`

Comment: Não funcionou o \+ , mas sim com \\+ , obrigado!!

Comment: @FelipeKrause , no caso do Java, o caracter de escape precisa ser escapado para ter efeito no `replace`. Por isso as duas barras. O resultado "compilado" da sua string (digamos assim) é `\+`, como o @AndersonCarlosWoss falou

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 5):

O caractere `+` é reservado em expressões regulares, então é necessário escapá-lo, porém no `Java` o caractere `\` é utilizado para escapar expressões dentro da `String`, então há a necessidade de utilizá-lo duas vezes para garantir o uso literal. Substituindo na sua expressão ficaria dessa forma:

```
teste = teste.replaceAll("\\+", "e");
```

O `+` depois de uma sequência de caracteres quer dizer "uma ou mais ocorrências", como por exemplo: `[0-9]+` que significa "uma ou mais ocorrências de um número (de zero a nove).